# Organize values of nested tuples in a single tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I'm extracting features from a specific class of objects I have and decided to built a method that extracts all features at once, i.e. call all feature extraction methods and return them in a tuple, as shown below.

```
def extractFeatures(self):
    if self.getLength()<=10:
        return ()
    else:
        return (self.getMean(),     # a number
            self.getStd(),     # a number
            self.getSkew(),     # a number
            self.getKurt(),     # a number
            # Many other methods here, such as:
            self.getACF(), # which returns a TUPLE of numbers...
            )
```

Nevertheless, I have some methods returning tuples with numbers instead of individual numbers, and since I'm still doing some tests and varying the length in each one of these tuples, hard typing `self.getACF()[0], self.getACF()[1], self.getACF()[2], ...` is not a good idea.

Is there a pythonic way of getting these values already "unpacked" so that I can return a tuple of only numbers instead of numbers and maybe nested tuples of indefinite size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a `list` of the values to `return`, then convert to a tuple at the end. This lets you use `append` for single values and `extend` for tuples:

```
def extractFeatures(self):
    if self.getLength() > 10:
        out = [self.getMean(), self.getStd(), self.getSkew()]
        out.append(self.getKurt()] # single value
        out.extend(self.getACF()) # multiple values
        return tuple(out)
```

Note that this will implicitly `return None` if `self.getLength()` is `10` or less.

However, bear in mind that your calling function now needs to know exactly what numbers are coming and in what order. An alternative in this case is to return a dictionary:

```
return {'mean': self.getMean(), ... 'ACF': self.getACF()}
```

Now the calling function can easily access the features required by key, and you can pass these as keyword arguments to other functions with dictionary unpacking:

```
def func_uses_mean_and_std(mean=None, std=None, **kwargs):
    ...

features = instance.extractFeatures()
result = func_uses_mean_and_std(**features)
```

Comment: Lists are better than tuples and do what I need :) and I liked the idea of a dictionary, but in this case I would be stuck in the same problem of having another bunch of numbers as a value for the ``'ACF'`` key. Is it still possible to decompose it into ``'ACF_0','ACF_1',...`` keys in an elegant way?

Comment: @rafa you could just leave `ACF` in a list within the dictionary, then access them `features['ACF'][0]` etc. when required. Trying to dynamically create variables is generally a bad idea.